# redirect does not redirecting properly in django

Tags: django, redirect, django-views

I am using django 1.10. This is my sample code. The problem is after calling redirection, the address bar populated with the follow addresses. It should directly redirected to google news. But it does not. How can I solve it?

```
def redirect_url_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    // done something
    url = "http://www.news.google.com/news"

    return redirect(url)
```

> http://localhost:8000/www.news.google.com.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/news

And in the console contains following:

> "GET /www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/www.news.google.com/news HTTP/1.1" 302 0

Can anybody tell what is the problem!!!

My pdb:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add **http://** before your required URL,

like:

```
  url = 'http://www.news.google.com/news'
```

Comment: Sorry, the output is the same. :(

Comment: It worked for me before.. I don't know why not this time.. I received some code in the view, processed it and redirected to some address.. very simple task.. :(

Comment: Try commenting everything other than the`url = ""` and the `**return redirect(url)**` line and check if it redirects on accessing the url.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your with http://www.news.google.com/news

```
def redirect_url_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # do something
    url = "http://www.news.google.com/news"

    return redirect(url)
```

Comment: Sorry, the output is the same. :(

Comment: Did you put a '/' in before the url? If not please share your urls.py

Comment: this is  url(r'^(?P<code>[a-zA-Z0-9]{5})', redirect_url_view),
it will receive some code

Comment: This is the pdb: contains http://
(Pdb) url
'http://www.news.google.com/news'
(Pdb)

Comment: Please paste the new redirect_url_view

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like

```
def redirect_url_view(request, *args, **kwargs):  
    return redirect('https://news.google.com/news/')
```

This should work